# How to add my Android Eclipse project to my friend's Git repository in Windows?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, git, version-control

I think I need to use Git clone?

His repository address is gitosis@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:repoName.git

I would like to do this outside of Eclipse. (ie. no plugins)

Pretend the path to my project is C://user/krb/project/..

Can I get a detailed answer on how to do this? I would like an application that allows me to use the command line as if I was on Linux.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) to install Git and bash cmd line.

I used Bash Git that was installed with mysysgit to change my directory to where I wanted the repository.

I then used the command git clone gitosis@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:repoName.git to clone buddies repo.

**side notes:** - I used [puttygen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to generate a key to open with [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and then sent that key to my friend for him to allow my key. Additionally, when installing msysgit on Windows don't install in the program files directory or you won't have permission to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseGIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) might be useful to you